# Cmd doesn't pass arguments to powershell script

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have a powershell script that I want to run from the command line (cmd, not powershell):

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "MyScript.ps1" -ScriptParam1 2020 -ScriptParam2 "bla" -ScriptParam3 "blub"
```

When I paste this code in powershell everything works fine but when I paste it in cmd, powershell starts and prompts me for the script parameters because they're mandatory. Why are those arguments not recognized in cmd?

Here is the content of MyScript

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [int] $ScriptParam1,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string] $ScriptParam2,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string] $ScriptParam3
)

$PSVersionTable
```

Comment: Worked fine for me. Worked just as well removing **-File** and the parameter names as well.
**powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass MyScript.ps1 2020 "bla" "blub"**

Comment: Works fine as is in Microsoft Windows  `[Version 10.0.19041.388]` and PowerShell `PSVersion 5.1.19041.1` and using the following script body  `$MyInvocation.BoundParameters`

Comment: What is the content of `MyScript.ps1`, specifically the `param`

Comment: Hmm I just noticed it runs fine on a different machine. I don't have access to the original machine so I can't check which versions are running there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are outside command request, meaning, your script call.

Try it this way...

```
# Contents of hello.ps1
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Scripts\hello.ps1'
# Results
<#
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]

Param
(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Domain",Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$ScriptParam1,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Domain",Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$ScriptParam2,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Domain",Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$ScriptParam3
)



$host
$PSversionTable
Write-Host 'Hello World'
Get-Date
#>
powershell.exe -NoExit -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "D:\Scripts\hello.ps1 -ScriptParam1 param1 -ScriptParam2 param2 -ScriptParam3 param3"
# Results
<#
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.1.19041.1
...

Key   : PSVersion
Value : 5.1.19041.1
...

Hello World
...
#>

powershell.exe -NoExit -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "D:\Scripts\hello.ps1 -ScriptParam1 param1 -ScriptParam2 param2 -ScriptParam3 param3"
# Results
<#
C:\>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.388]

C:\>powershell.exe -NoExit -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "D:\Scripts\hello.ps1 -ScriptParam1 param1 -ScriptParam2 param2 -ScriptParam3 param3"


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.1.19041.1
...

Key   : PSVersion
Value : 5.1.19041.1
...

Hello World
...


C:\>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.388]

C:\>powershell.exe -NoExit -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "D:\Scripts\hello.ps1"

cmdlet hello.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ScriptParam1: 1
ScriptParam2: 2
ScriptParam3: 3


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.1.19041.1
...

Key   : PSVersion
Value : 5.1.19041.1
...

Hello World
...
#>
```

Parsing happens a bit differently when you are already in a PowerShell instance than when you are starting one from cmd.exe. Cmd.exe and to read it all first, and cmd.exe has no idea what those -ScriptParam* are, thus they are ignored.

As per the example shown.

Comment: Hmm I've tested the same code on a different machine and it runs perfectly fine. Not sure what causes the problem on my other machine. Are there any differences between cmd versions?

Comment: Nope, cmd.exe has been the way it is for years now. No real changes. So, did you try my suggestion above on those choking machines?

Comment: Not yet. Takes a couple of days until I have access to those again. I'll report back.

Comment: No worries and understood.

Comment: Alright tested it and it works. Surprisingly, my version now works as well and I have no idea why it didn't before...